# ASP.NET [from metadata]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was stepping through some code and hit a method I wanted to see the code for. I clicked on 'go to definition' and it would usually take me to the method definition, but now it takes me to what appears to be an auto generated [from metadata] class. I've never experienced this before. What's going on and how do I get the old functionality back?

If it helps, the method is being called in a code behind file and the method definition is in the code behind of a UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

Because the assembly is compiled. You will see this when stepping into a MS assembly. You can use .NET [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), it is free, to inspect the code.

Comment: Thanks. What I don't get is, about half an hour ago when I clicked 'go to definition', it would take me to the actual code, but now it takes me the metadata code. I'm not sure what I did to change the behavior. If I choose any other random method in my code and 'go to definition' it takes me to the method's code.

Comment: Is the code you are trying to go to in the same project? Or is it a referenced assembly?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you set the reference from a dll file or project.

Using dll files only allows you to go to the method's signature. "[from metadata]" shows you that you are looking into a precompiled file.
In the other hand, when you add a project reference, the IDE can get the actual file's location and open it.